# Access restriction with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, security, ember.js

I have an application done fully in JavaScript using Ember.js. What I want help with is the following:

1. I have two account types: basic and premium.
2. Depending on what account type the user have I wish to display ads him.
3. The user can use parts of my application only if he has a premium account.

What I must have in mind in order to protect my application so it's secure against people trying to use premium features without having that privilege? Because all Javascript will be sent as a single file, people can just look at all my app code and maybe reverse it or even copy it and use locally without even entering my site, which would put all my effort to waste.

Comment: The best you can try to do is obscure your code, you can't secure this model.

Comment: You can try packing your code but no approach is going to be absolutely tamperproof.

Answer (score 3):

Your client side code shouldn't be considered more than sugar for the user's experience, not a layer that is trusted.

That means your backend should be pessimistic in nature, not trusting requests from the client, but making sure they can make said request, and sanitizing any data sent to them assuming the user is trying to do harm.